# CSS3 3d transform in unsupported browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to implement a similar feature as here: http://demo.marcofolio.net/3d_animation_css3/. But I need it to work in all browsers. Is there any JQuery plugin that can implement 3D Transform feature in unsupported browsers like Opera? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this plugin http://transformjs.strobeapp.com/.

EDIT: Above link is dead now, visit this one instead: https://github.com/sproutcore/TransformJS

Answer (score 1):

you can use TransformJS plugin or Sprite3D plugin, they improve the support of 3D and 2D CSS Transforms in all major browsers:

http://transformjs.strobeapp.com/
http://minimal.be/lab/Sprite3D/